# Python3 decoding binary string with hex numbers higher than \x7f

Tags: python-3.x, string, binary, thrift

i try to port some bmv2 thrift python2 code to python3 and have the following problem:

python2:

```
import struct
def demo(byte_list):
   f = 'B' * len(byte_list)
   r = struct.pack(f, *byte_list)
   return r
demo([255, 255])
"\xff\xff"
```

ported to python3 it returns a binary string **b"\xff\xff"** because the struct module changed.
If i try to decode by **r.decode()** an exception throws because **\xff** is reserved in the unicode table.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

The easiest solution would be to concatenate the string by myself. I tried with a self made string like **"\x01"** and it works, if i try **"\xff"** it does not work with thrift. I think because **"\xff"** is **"ÿ"** in unicode and the thrift server expects **"\xff"**. 
I tried different encodings and raw strings.

TL;DR: Is there any way to decode a binary string containing \xff or in general higher than \x7f (which is ord 127) in python3? **b"\xff" => "x\ff"** OR use the old python2 struct import?

Comment: The issue is that "\xff\xff" genuinely isn't a string: it's a byte sequence representing a binary object. Python 2 didn't distinguish between the two but Python 3 does. What are you using the output for, and can't you just use the bytes object instead?

Comment: The output gets passed to the thrift module which expects a "normal" string apparently, if i pass the binary string i get an exception at "python3.5/site-packages/thrift/compat.py" (encoding without a string argument)

Comment: This looks like a big in thrift (perhaps https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-python/issues/151). Are you using the latest version?

Comment: thanks for the advice, i've upgraded from 0.11 to 0.12 but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: That's a pity. Hopefully somebody else will be able to solve this!

Comment: Consider filing a JIRA ticket and/or discussing on the [Thrift mailing list](https://thrift.apache.org/mailing).  Also, the 0.13.0 is under preparation. Not a Python user myself, so can't tell